# SQL join with distinct column on one table

Tags: sql, oracle

Maybe I'm searching using the wrong words because I can't find the answer elswhere, but I need to join two tables but make sure the ID from one of the tables is distinct.  Something like the below:

```
SELECT B.COLUMN_A, B.COLUMN_B, B.COLUMN_C
FROM TABLE1 A
JOIN TABLE2 B
ON (Distinct) A.COLUMN_A = B.COLUMN_A;
```

The value `A.COLUMN_A` from `TABLE1` needs to be `DISTINCT`.

I've tried the below but that didn't work:

```
SELECT B.COLUMN_A, B.COLUMN_B, B.COLUMN_C
FROM TABLE1 A
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_A FROM TABLE2) B
ON A.COLUMN_A = B.COLUMN_A;
```

I keep getting a ORA-00904: invalid identifer error on `B.COLUMN_C`.  If I try to use `) AS B` then I get a ORA-00905: missing keyword error.

Comment: It's chocking on the alias `B`.  Not sure why...

Comment: maybe this example can be useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/2639114/5609420

Comment: @AlexS that answer looks identical to the one I already tried.

Comment: "*invalid identifer error on B.COLUMN_C*" - of course it does complain about this. You are only selecting `column_a` inside the derived table. And therefore there is no `b.column_c` only a `b.column_a`. Please add some sample data and the expected output based on that data (formatted text please,  no screen shots)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yep, I just noticed this myself.  But if I `(SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C FROM TABLE2)` that defeats the purpose of the `DISTINCT`.  I only want it to be distinct based on just `COLUMN_A`.

Comment: And which value of `column_b` and `column_c` should be chosen? This can't really be answered without sample data.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The more I talk about this the more silly it sounds, but the truth is that I don't care which one is chosen.  In the end I only care about removing one of the duplicates based on the value in `A.COLUMN_A`.  The values found in COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, and COLUM_C have all been identical.  It makes me think I could actually just use distinct in my select after the join happens.

Comment: You need values from B, matching A, but only the rows for which the value  of column_a only appears one time in B; am i right?

Comment: @Aleksej Correct, but because there are two rows with the same value in COLUMN_A it appears twice after joining.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the other values, use `group by`

```
SELECT b.column_a, b.column_b, b.column_c
FROM table1 a
  JOIN (
    SELECT column_a, max(column_b) as column_b, max(column_c) as column_c
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY column_a
  ) b ON a.column_a = b.column_a
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `ROW_NUMBER` to get a single row per `COLUMN_A`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 A
JOIN
 (
   SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COLUMN_A ORDER BY COLUMN_A) AS rn
   FROM table2
 ) B
ON A.column_a = B.column_a
AND B.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
 select * from 
(
    select column_a,column_b,column_c
    from 
        (
            select  column_a,column_b,column_c, count(1) over (partition by column_a) as num
            from tableB
        )
    where num = 1
)tB
inner join tableA
using (column_a)
```

The double nesting is not necessary, but I hope it makes the query more readable

Answer (score 0):

If you need col_a, col_b, col_c and want to ensure col_a never repeats and col_b, col_c values are not germane, then :

```
SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c 
FROM table2 
WHERE rowid in ( SELECT min(rowid) 
                 FROM table2 A , table1 B )
                 WHERE B.col_a = A.col_a 
                 GROUP BY A.col_a )
```

In above you choose one distinct row of Table2 that is also present in Table1. Then using that row's id you select all three columns.

Answer (score 0):

You are not selecting any of the columns from `TABLE1`, so your join to (distinct) `TABLE1` records is really just a semi-join, which is most easily expressed as:

```
SELECT B.COLUMN_A, B.COLUMN_B, B.COLUMN_C
FROM TABLE2 B
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 'at least one row in table1' 
               FROM   TABLE1 A
               WHERE  A.COLUMN_A = B.COLUMN_A );
```