# Join of Two Tables where Data Matches in One Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

For some reason I have a hard time grasping joins and this one should be very simple with the knowledge that I have in SQL.

Anyway, I have 2 tables. We will call them TableA and TableB. One of the columns in TableA is "ID". TableB only consists of the column "ID". I want to return all rows in TableA whose ID is present in TableB.

I know this should be very simple to figure out, but my brain doesn't want to work today.

Comment: I would use `EXISTS` or `IN`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select distinct ... inner join vs. select ... where id in (...)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638989/select-distinct-inner-join-vs-select-where-id-in)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL JOIN and different types of JOINs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946221/sql-join-and-different-types-of-joins)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using an `EXISTS`:

```
Select  A.*
From    TableA  A
Where   Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    TableB  B
    Where   A.Id = B.Id
)
```

You can also use a `JOIN` if you wish, but depending on your data, you may want to couple that with a `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
Select  Distinct A.*
From    TableA  A
Join    TableB  B   On  A.Id = B.Id
```

One thing to keep in mind is that the `ID` of `TableA` is not necessarily related to the `ID` of `TableB`.

Comment: Thank you this worked! Now how would I update what was selected in TableA? I tried replacing "select A.* from" with "update" and set what I need to update after that line, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @chrisdoubleu13 You should be able to change it to `UPDATE A SET . . . FROM TableA A WHERE . . .`

Comment: Got it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

this should work

```
 SELECT B.ID 
 FROM TableA A 
 JOIN TableB B 
 ON (A.ID=B.ID)
 WHERE A.ID=B.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **IN** operator like this:

```
Select  *
From    TableA 
Where   ID in
(
    Select distinct ID
    From    TableB
)
```